# Let X be an infinite set. (a) Let $ \tau $ be the cofinite topology over X. Show that (X, $ \tau $) is $ T_1 $ and that if $ \sigma $ is ...

Tags: general-topology

Let X be an infinite set.

(a) Let $ \tau $ be the co-finite topology over X. Show that (X, $ \tau $) is $ T_1 $ and that if $ \sigma $ is another topology over X such that (X, $ \sigma $ ) is $ T_1 $ then $ \tau $ $ \subset $ $ \sigma $
.

(b) Show that there is no topology over X that is the lowest $ T_2 $ over topology X

.........................................................................................................

Let x, y $ \in $ X and x $\neq $ y, we have U = X \ {y} and V = X \ {x} open such that x $ \in $ U and y $ \in $ V, but x $ \notin $ V and $ \notin $ U, therefore is $ T_1 $.

Is this part correct ?

What about the rest? I'm not sure how to proceed, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer/hint: In the heading of the question you have added an escaped "tau" instead of $\tau$

Comment: Hint: Being $T_1$ is equivalent to singletons being closed sets. I don't understand (b)

Answer (score 1):

You have indeed shown that the cofinite topology on $X$ is $T_1$. To complete (a), you must show that if $\sigma$ is any $T_1$ topology on $X$, then $\tau\subseteq\sigma$; in other words, the cofinite topology is the smallest $T_1$ topology on $X$, because it is contained in every $T_1$ topology on $X$.

In order to do this, you must show that each $U\in\tau$ also belongs to $\sigma$. Suppose that $U\in\tau$; then either $U=\varnothing$, which is certainly in $\sigma$, or $U=X\setminus F$ for some finite $F\subseteq X$. Use the fact that $\sigma$ is a $T_1$ topology to show that the finite set $F$ is closed with respect to $\sigma$ and hence that $U\in\sigma$.

For (b) you must show that there is no $T_2$ topology $\tau$ on $X$ that is contained in every $T_2$ topology on $X$. In other words, you must show that if $\tau$ is a $T_2$ topology on $X$, there is a $T_2$ topology $\sigma$ on $X$ such that $\tau\nsubseteq\sigma$. I do not at the moment see any very simple way to do this. Here is the simplest approach that has so far occurred to me.

First show that there is a family $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of pairwise disjoint, non-empty open sets in $X$; you will need to use the hypotheses that $X$ is infinite and $\tau$ is $T_2$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x_n\in U_n$, and let $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$\tau_n=\{V\in\tau:x_n\in V\subseteq U_n\}\,;$$

$\tau_n$ is a local base at $x_n$.

Let $\varphi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$ be a bijection. Let $\tau_{\Bbb Q}$ be the usual topology on $\Bbb Q$. Define a new topology $\sigma$ on $X$ as follows:

- Each point of $X\setminus A$ is isolated.
- If $x_n\in A$, $W$ is a $\sigma$-nbhd of $x_n$ iff there is a $V\in\tau_{\Bbb Q}$ such that $\varphi(n)\in V$, and for each $k\in\varphi^{-1}[V]$ there is a $W_k\in\tau_k$ such that $W_k\subseteq W$.

Verify that this $\sigma$ is a $T_2$ topology on $X$. Check that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $U_n\notin\sigma$, so $\tau\nsubseteq\sigma$.